# When MathJax works on MathOverflow but not Math Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, mathjax

I had been away from MSE for a month and a half, ending about last week.  When I started looking at MSE again, the MathJax appeared unrendered on my screen, and when I answer a question, no separate box displaying my answer appears (although from the reactions of other readers, they can read the answers and see normally rendered MathJax.

I would guess that this was something done by my system (I am not the admin of my system) and that MathJax support was considered by the security or IT gurus to be "superfluous" except for one puzzling fact:  When I go ointo MathOverflow, the MathJax works fine, my answers appear rendered as I go in the usual box, and in general everything is fine.

Does anybody know a clue about what might be going on with this?  I thought it might have something to do with the experimental 6.2 release, which appeared in a Meta hot topic the day I started logging in again, but I think now that this is a coincidence, since I didn't do anything to get the new release.

Two more clues:

My questions don't appear in a separate box either, and this behavior goes for both MSE and MSE Meta.

And every time I submit a question or an answer I have to solve an easy captcha, which does not happen on MathOverflow.  (Actually, I am *not* sure whether I am human any more, but I try to work under the assumption that I am...)

Thanks

Comment: You don't have to do anything to get beta version of MathJax here: the site loads it from `//beta.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js` automatically. On MathOverflow it's `//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js` Just a guess: some setting was changed to block script load, and it still works for you on MO because your browser has the script cached. Do you get any error messages in the browser's console? (And what is the browser, by the way?)

Comment: I see no error messages on the console; the only active behavior is the captcha box. My browser is Chrome, but I get the same behavior on IE. I rebooted (that is something I can do on my own initiative) and the behavior did not change, so if it was a cached script, it is cached in a way that survives restarts. I suspect that if MSE is loading beta.mathjx, something in that clashes with some (changed) setting on my system. Any way to force loading cdn.mathjax instead, so I can test this guess?

Comment: Possible, but an easier way to localize the problem is to check out other sites: [cs.se], [dsp.se], [stats.se]. Does Mathjax work there?

Comment: Yes, it works fine on both Computer Science and Signal Processing.

Comment: And also Cross Validated

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "open the console":  Just lonk-clicking on the reload button in the browser has the same effect as ordinary clicking; no options involving the cache appear.  The three lines on the right (the "tools" button) does let me clear browsing data in More Tools, but this does not change the behavior, and I could not find anything about caching.

Comment: When the developer console is open (F12), the reload button changes its behavior: pressing and holding it offers more reload options. (It's not exactly intuitive interface.)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the F12.  I have done the empy cache and hard reload, and the behavior still persists.BTW, although I have not used CHAT, the site is suggesting that we move this discussion to CHAT.

Comment: Mark, can you access the beta domain at all, e.g. https://beta.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/examples.html?

Comment: Also, do you see any errors in the developer tools if you open them with F12 and then refresh?

Comment: Aha, beta.mathjax.org is "blocked by my organization."  This is probably the problem.  And if I click in the console on the beta.mathjax.org line, I see in gray "failed to load response data.